# Is there any way to filter the questions based on interesting tags?

Tags: feature-request, support, questions, tags

If I click on a tag I get all questions marked with that tag. But is there any way to filter the questions on the tags that I've choosen as interesting?

I'm adding this as a feature request, it would be great if this was possible to filter the questions based on my interests.

On the [Unanswered questions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/unanswered) there is a tab for [My tags](https://gis.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=mytags) that's the functionality I would like on [Questions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions) as well.

Comment: I don't think I could write a better response than is given in the search options FAQ, listed here http://gis.stackexchange.com/search

Comment: @andy-w Ok, am I understanding it FAQ correctly that the answer is no, not without entering all tag in the search.

Comment: Thats the way it looks to me, you can also mix tags and free text search, like this http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=[web-mapping]+studies

Comment: Also I'm not quite sure what your suggesting, because if you have alot of "interesting" tags this would become impracticable, unless you could pick and choose which tags, but then you would be back to what we have currently.

Comment: @andy-w Well as a developer and ESRI partner, my my main interest is tags like esri, arcobjects, arcgis, development, so to be able to what's happend in my field since I last visited by clicking on button instead of writing a long search string would be great.

Comment: @Mathias, you could always mark a specific search string as a bookmark to reduce the repetitiveness of typing in to look for particular tags. I just personally don't see much need for a feature like this when you can already accomplish this and more through the current search function. I also just looked and you can sign up for an RSS feed for particular tags, which I would prefer to searching the web-page periodically.

Answer (score 2):

You can use wildcards in your tag filter. For instance, I have arc* in my ignored tag list because I don't use, and know little about any ESRI products.

Comment: This could be unfortunate because many interesting questions have nothing to do with the software and attract some great software-neutral answers.  For instance, I don't use GRASS but have enjoyed some of the answers appearing in GRASS-tagged questions, especially about the hydrology tools.  You might consider flagging the Arc* stuff specifically, such as ignoring ArcObjects and ArcSDE (which will focus on arcane programming issues), but allowing generic ArcGIS* tags.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible from the site itself, but check for browser extensions (e.g., Firefox add-ons, or perhaps Greasemonkey scripts).  I definitely had this before on StackOverflow, although I can't remember exactly what it was.